# Golang: What to return when building an SDK to interact with a Web API?

Tags: oop, go, design-patterns, sdk

I'm building an SDK for a web application using Go.

I was wondering what the best form of returning data to users of the SDK would be.

For example, below is a function that takes in an http.Request object. What is the preferred object/struct that should be returned from this function?

```
func runRequest(request *http.Request) map[string]interface{} {
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(request)
    //handle error
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    var data map[string]interface{}
    err2 := json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &data)
    //handle error

    return data
}
```

Comment: First and foremost, this question is entirely opinion-based, so off-topic for SO. Second, your function is unexported, so it is not part of your SDK. Third, it is highly unusual for a web API SDK to take a `http.Request` - that's not an SDK, that's just a thin wrapper around `net/http`.

Comment: I would like to know the different options I have to form my opinions about the topic, if that makes sense.

Comment: @RiaruNeimu it makes sense but on stackoverflow opinion based questions are offtopic, your particular question is a better fit for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this simple example you can use the same approach that `json.Unmarshal` uses. That is, your function takes a pointer to a value into which you want to unmarshal the response's body.

```
func RunRequest(request *http.Request, dst interface{}) error {
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    return json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(dst)
}
```

Comment: But note that this really isn't an SDK; this is a completely generic REST request helper for absolutely any JSON REST API.

Comment: I agree @Adrian, my intention was only to provide an example of what I think is a more idiomatic api for the given function, especially when compared to the `map[string]interface{}` approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you subscribe to ["Clean Architecture"](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) or ["Hexagonal Architecture"](http://fideloper.com/hexagonal-architecture) `runRequest` should return something from your domain.  Ie what are you actually requesting? (what's the name of the resource? Page? Car? Account?)

I would argue the example you posted is the inverse of Clean Architecture.  It shows the protocols and technologies and is asking what is optimal when Clean Architecture suggests that the transport protocols are an implementation detail.  Focusing on your domain (ie what you're fetching and the operatations you allow performed on them) will help to decouple them from your implementation or transport protocols.

For example pretend your request is for a User, and associated Account, and Pages belonging to that user.  Focusing on their relationships

ie User.Accounts() or Account.Pages() is a nice trick to create more decoupled software.  What if you're offering a GRPC connection? What if you want to support multiple return types? JSON, XML, Protobuf?

Clean architecture addresses this by focusing on the domain objects in the first cirlce, and then then the encoding in outer circle.  This means the inner circle, knows nothing about the encodings, (ie the encodings are dependent on your domain objects but your domain objects aren't dependent on the encodings)

If your function above is requesting an account

```
type Account struct {
   Name string
   ID string
   Location string
}
```

Then there would be another layer that knows how to encode the account:

```
type JSONAccount struct {
    Account
}

func (ja JSONAccount) Encode() ([]byte, error) {
   return json.Marshal(ja)
}
```

Your `runRequest` function could operate on an [interface](https://gobyexample.com/interfaces)

```
type Encoder interface {
   Encode() ([]byte, error)
}
```

Now you could support multiple different encodings for your return types, and expose them as a flag to the caller.  Since your function depends on an interface it will be able to operate or return multiple different data encoders as long as they fulfill the interface!!

Comment: Thanks for the help on how to structure my processes better. Another thing I was wondering is how I should be interacting with different types of objects I am requesting. Supposing I want to create a generic API service handler that can handle different responses for example.

Comment: Go addresses this through "Interfaces" if you google go interfaces there are many amazing blogs and tutorials https://blog.chewxy.com/2018/03/18/golang-interfaces/, https://medium.com/golangspec/interfaces-in-go-part-i-4ae53a97479c